# How should we structure the page in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js

I am thinking about how to organize the structure of page.jsx and the structure of the file in nextjs13.
Recently, I learned the concept of atomic design.
Is it a good way to separate file that fetcing data from api and html tags?(like page.jsx and template.jsx)
I would like to know a structurally well-organized best practice at Nextjs.